# How do i add Options to the xorg conf?

Tags: touchpad, libinput

Where is, and how do I change the xorg conf file?

I want to change the default scrolling speed of my touchpad.
I can use `xinput --set-prop "YOUR TOUCHPAD" "libinput Scrolling Pixel Distance" YOUR_SPEED` to change it for this session, but I would like to make it permanent.

I've read here [https://man.archlinux.org/man/libinput.4#Option~24](https://man.archlinux.org/man/libinput.4#Option%7E24), that I can change the `Option "ScrollPixelDistance" "int"` but I don't know how to do this or where to find the xorg config file.

Answer (score 0):

### Proper Format

The proper section is listed under **Synopsis**:

```
Section "InputDevice"
  Identifier "devname"
  Driver "libinput"
  Option "Device"   "devpath"
  ...
EndSection
```

You add the Option under the other Options as in:

```
Option "Device"         "devpath"
Option "ScroillPixelDistance" "5"
```

This gives you a distance of 5 pixels as an example. Quoting:

> SCROLL PIXEL DISTANCE
>
> The X server does not support per-pixel scrolling but it does support smooth scrolling. All scroll events however are based around a logical unit of scrolling (traditionally corresponding to a wheel click). It is thus not possible to scroll by 10 pixels, but it is possible for a driver to scroll by 1/10th of a logical wheel click.
>
> libinput provides scroll data in pixels. The ScrollPixelDistance option defines the amount of movement equivalent to one wheel click. For example, a value of 50 means the user has to move a finger by 50 pixels to generate one logical click event and each pixel is 1/50th of a wheel click.

Comment: i think you are one step ahead. How do i add the option? do i change a file somewhere? do i run a specific command? i am confused *where* the article is telling me to make the change

Comment: Try `man xorg.conf`  The file location for auto-configuration is `/etc/xorg.conf.d/` and the manual file is `/etc/xorg.conf`.  See also: [XOrg: ArchWiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/xorg)